# working with cachekeys Enterprise Edition 1.9

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, block-cache, caching

So I want to make sure magentos FPC doesn't mess things up in my header.  Based upon some logic I will load one of two sections.  Here is my thinking thus far:

On view: create key(1) or create key(2)

On subsequent views: access key(1) or key(2)

How do I fill these caches with my content?  I only need two different versions of the section -- it is not *really* dynamic.

Comment: Sounds like you wish to do some hole punching? This is a nice little extension/tutorial that can walk you through the ropes. http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/03/overcoming-magentos-full-page-cache-through-hole-punching/

Comment: @PhilB That doesn't actually explain how to do it.

Comment: @easymoden00b were you able to solve this problem? If so, how?